# Summing database column in python

Tags: python, database

I have recently encountered the problem of adding the elements of a database column. Here is the following code:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("values.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT objects FROM data WHERE firm = "sony"')
```

As you can see, I connect to the database (sql) and I tell to Python to select the column "objects".

The problem is that I do not know the appropriate command for summing the selected objects.

Any ideas/ advices are highly reccomended.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you provide additional detail? Unclear what you mean by "summing the selected retweets".

Comment: Sorry i was meaning objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, have the database do the sum, as that reduces data transfer and lets the database do what it's good at.

```
cur.execute("SELECT sum(objects) FROM data WHERE firm = 'sony'")
```

or, if you're really just looking for the total count of objects.

```
cur.execute("SELECT count(objects) FROM data WHERE firm = 'sony'")
```

either way, your result is simply:

```
count = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
```

Comment: thanks much! is there another way apart from fetchall?

Comment: @lavezzi7, there are always other ways, but think of results of cur.execute() as a list of lists -- it's really the list of rows (even if only one row), with each row containing a list of columns (even if only one column).

Comment: You always want to drain the results from the database, so using fetchall() is perfect for this. Play with sqllite3 & check out [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line:

```
print sum([ row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()])
```

If you want the items instead adding them together:

```
print ([ row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()])
```